# Dynamic query in PIVOT IN clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to write a dynamic query inside In clause of pivot query in oracle 11g. With Pivot xml, it is possible, but I do not need the xml one. Here is the code snippet.

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
    select cu.id, u.topic, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email,
        trunc(cu.REGISTRATION_DATE) Register_Date,
        trunc(min(u.view_date)) First_Visit,
        trunc(max(u.view_date)) Last_Visit,
        nvl(sum(u.user_visits),0) Visits,
        nvl(sum(u.time_in_topic),0) Time_in_Topic,
        ffl.label label, ffv.field_value val
    from ACTIVE_USER_VIEWS_BY_TOPIC u
    LEFT join cl_user cu
        on u.user_id=cu.id
    LEFT JOIN CL_PROFILE_FIELD_LABEL ffl
        on ffl.cl_customer_accounts_id=cu.cl_customer_accounts_id
    LEFT  JOIN CL_PROFILE_FIELD_VALUE ffv
        on ffl.id = ffv.profile_field_label_id  and ffv.user_id= cu.id
    LEFT  JOIN CL_PROFILE_FIELD_ASSIGNMENT ffa
        on ffl.id = ffa.profile_field_label_id
    where ffl.cl_customer_accounts_id = (
        select cl_customer_accounts_id
        from CL_USER where ID =  cu.id)
    and ffl.ENABLED = 'Y'
    and  u.PURCHASED_PRODUCT_ID  = 582002861
    and  REGEXP_LIKE  (u.topic,
        'difficult_interactions|customer_focus|leading_people' )
    group by cu.id, u.topic, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email,
    cu.REGISTRATION_DATE, trunc(u.view_date,'MONTH'), ffl.label,
    ffv.field_value
)
SELECT *
FROM   pivot_data
PIVOT (
     max(val)
     FOR label
     IN ('Flexfield1' AS Flexfield1, 'Flexfield2' AS Flexfield2,
         'Flexfield3' AS Flexfield3, 'Flexfield4' AS Flexfield4,
         'Flexfield5' AS Flexfield5, 'Flexfield6' AS Flexfield6,
         'flexfield021' AS flexfield021, 'sdcs' AS sdcs)
  )
```

I have the query for dynamic data creation i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LISTAGG('''' || label || ''' AS ' || label,',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY label) AS temp_in_statement 
    FROM (
        select distinct label
        from cl_profile_field_label
        where cl_customer_accounts_id=(
            select cl_customer_accounts_id
            from cl_purchased_product
            where id=582002861));
```

But if I put the dynamic query inside pivot IN clause, I am getting the error as `ORA-00936: missing expression`. Please help me out.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave us a sqlfiddle link or prepare the input with the CTE or scripts

Comment: Not 100% sure, but don't believe there is a way to do exactly what you are looking for.  Is it possible for you to dynamically create your entire statement though?

Comment: Kindly Refer this - It will definitely help you.
[Dynamic Column Generation - Pivot [SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947431/i-want-to-generate-sql-query-output-like-screenshot/46952452#46952452)