# I want to generate SQL query output like screenshot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting data like below screenshot using `select VendorShortName,BasePrice,convert(varchar, ModifiedDate,101) as date from prices where barcode='8712566383849'`

[image]

Now for generating the graph, I need data like below screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to group and sum the value. Here some example.. SELECT VendorShortName, convert(varchar, ModifiedDate,101) as date, SUM( BasePrice ) FROM prices GROUP BY VendorShortName,date;

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by using PIVOT. Here is example how you will get that. Firt Image will show you simple PIVOT Query and how you achieve that.

Second Image Will show you dynamic Query generation - which might be more helpful as based on your image it seems you require to generate dynamic columns 
so please refer second image for the same.

[image]

[image]

Based on query i have created below snippet - see if it helps you.

```html
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(vendorshortname)
FROM (select distinct vendorshortname from Prices) AS Prices

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ModifiedDate, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM (select VendorShortName,BasePrice,ModifiedDate from prices where barcode=''8712566383849'') As SourceTable 
PIVOT
 (avg(BasePrice) 
      FOR VendorShortName IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of database, `PIVOT` is what you use in these cases.  You will need to know the values of V1, V2 etc. or do dynamic SQL.

Traditionally though, this kind of manipulation is done at the client (graphing) side, not on the database because, as you are discovering, that transformed data is not a good fit to the relational model.